# Selecting different web elements with the same name

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use selenium with python to go through different tabs (buttons?) on a carousel so that I can collect data from each of them, but the problem is the webelement that I need to use is the same name for each tab (button).

I can find the following html code using .child and getting a list but I don't know how to do this with Selenium.

```
[<div class="rj-carousel-item" data-uat="carousel-item-sport"><span class="icon i-o-sport-2 i-32"></span><div class="rj-carousel-item__details"><div class="rj-carousel-item__sportName" data-uat="carousel-item-sportName">Basketball</div><div class="rj-carousel-item__eventsCount" data-uat="carousel-item-eventsCount">14</div></div></div>,
 <div class="rj-carousel-item" data-uat="carousel-item-sport"><span class="icon i-o-sport-8 i-32"></span><div class="rj-carousel-item__details"><div class="rj-carousel-item__sportName" data-uat="carousel-item-sportName">Ice Hockey</div><div class="rj-carousel-item__eventsCount" data-uat="carousel-item-eventsCount">10</div></div></div>,
 <div class="rj-carousel-item" data-uat="carousel-item-sport"><span class="icon i-o-sport-1 i-32"></span><div class="rj-carousel-item__details"><div class="rj-carousel-item__sportName" data-uat="carousel-item-sportName">Soccer</div><div class="rj-carousel-item__eventsCount" data-uat="carousel-item-eventsCount">11</div></div></div>,
 <div class="rj-carousel-item" data-uat="carousel-item-sport"><span class="icon i-o-sport-6 i-32"></span><div class="rj-carousel-item__details"><div class="rj-carousel-item__sportName" data-uat="carousel-item-sportName">Tennis</div><div class="rj-carousel-item__eventsCount" data-uat="carousel-item-eventsCount">14</div></div></div>
```

Now If I use

```
new_tab = driver.find_element_by_class_name('rj-carousel-item')
new_tab.click()
```

Then I can access the first tab, but I don't know how to get to the rest. Again, I'm assuming it has to do with making a list of these but I can't seem to figure out how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get list of elements Use `find_elements` which returns list and then you can iterate.

Use `find_elements_by_class_name()`:

```
listoftab=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("rj-carousel-item")
for new_tab in listoftab:
    new_tab.click()
```

Or `find_elements_by_css_selector()` :

```
listoftab=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".rj-carousel-item")
for new_tab in listoftab:
    new_tab.click()
```

Comment: I selected this as the "best" answer cause it answered exactly what I was looking for which was a list

Answer (score 1):

You can click with help of text.

```
tab = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[.='Basketball'])
tab.click()
```

Same way you can click on **soccer** and **tennis** too.

**OR**

Although you can use also get a list of element and iterate it with click

```
tabs=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("rj-carousel-item__sportName")
for tab in tabs:
    tab.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

To go through different tabs invoking `click()` you can write a method as follows:

```
def click_me(myString):
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='rj-carousel-item']//div[@class='rj-carousel-item__sportName'][.='" + myString + "']").click()
```

Now, you can call the method from your main method as follows:

```
click_me("Basketball")
click_me("Ice Hockey")
click_me("Soccer")
click_me("Tennis")
```

Comment: Thanks, I got so used to looking at the beginning of a tag i didn't notice the difference s.

Comment: @jon Pardon me, possibly I didn't get your comment. Did your question got addressed?

Comment: Yes, it did, I just selected the other answer since it specifically answered the question about getting back a list. Your answer is also correct, but more for a slightly different reason. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS you can do
div.rj-carousel-item:nth-of-type(2)